# GridView not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

for some reason I can't get a Gridview to display on my page.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" 
CssClass="auto-style2" Width="1057px" AutoGenerateColumns="true" 
ViewStateMode="Enabled">
    </asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["DirtyData"] != null)
            {
                Dirty dirty = Session["DirtyData"] as Dirty;
                char delimiter = '\t';

                DataTable customer = new DataTable();

                #region customer
                string[] customerCol1 = dirty.Customer[0].Split(delimiter);

                foreach (string col in customerCol1)
                {
                    DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
                    column.ColumnName = col;
                    customer.Columns.Add(column);
                    Response.Write(string.Format("Adding Customer Column: {0}<br />", col));
                }

                for (int i = 1; i < dirty.Customer.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataRow row = customer.NewRow();

                    string[] split = dirty.Customer[i].Split(delimiter);

                    for (int x = 0; x < split.Length; x++)
                    {
                        row[i] = split[x];
                    }
                    customer.Rows.Add(row);
                }

                Response.Write("binding customer<br />");
                gvCustomers.DataSource = customer;
                gvCustomers.DataBind();
                gvCustomers.Visible = true;
                #endregion

                Session["DirtyData"] = null;
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

the output shows the columns being added to the grid so I know the datatable has data in it but there is no grid showing on the page.

I don't see what I'm missing here.

Comment: show what event/method you are binding with data....  might be too late.

Comment: Just an experiment, try setting `EmptyDataText="No data found"` on `gvCustomers`.

Comment: @mason ok if there are no rows the columns wont display? I see 'No data found' showing.

Comment: Yes, exactly. No reason for the columns to display if there are no rows. Take a look at the data you're binding to the GridView and ensure it's not empty.

Comment: @mason ok I wasn't aware of that. Yes I know there are only columns and no rows currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is empty. You can verify this by adding EmptyDataText attribute.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" EmptyDataText="No data found!" 
CssClass="auto-style2" Width="1057px" AutoGenerateColumns="true" 
ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
```

No columns will be displayed if there is no data.

To fix, take a look at the data you're binding to the GridView. It'll be empty.

Answer (score -2):

You need to add columns to your gridview. To what you want to bind your datasource with? You have to specify BoundField or TemplateFields in gridview's columns property.

Comment: It has to be dynamic and not targeting any specific column names. Which is why I'm using autogeneratecolumns

Comment: -1 You don't need to manually add columns when using auto generate columns.